# I cannot open and install .deb file

Tags: deb

I am new in ubuntu . I downloded visual code in https://code.visualstudio.com/Download .deb file.
I when ı click anything happen

Answer (score 3):

Copy the file to your Home directory and run in a terminal

```
sudo apt install ./code_1.52.1-1608136922_amd64.deb
```

Comment: can u tel me where is terminal

Comment: Press Ctrl+Alt+T and it should open. Also there should be "Terminal" application among others.